# How can we implement undo / redo, image Rotation & Zoom in & Zoom Out methods in react-native without using Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing one sample application which includes images click or text dragging. I want to implement the UNDO and REDO functionality without using REDUX.

Please give me any sample demo those to methods, I researched about this methods. not get any luck.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**Please check this link for Zoom in/ Out.**

*https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-viewer*

Comment: This is not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this writeup given on the Redux GH repo. -

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.md

Also, check the links below for the different examples.

[todos-with-undo](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos-with-undo)

[redux-undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo)

For Zoom In/ Out -

https://medium.com/@mheavers/animating-zoom-in-react-native-scroll-view-16587b35a064

Comment: I dont know about redux can you share without redux

Comment: hi, @akshay gore thanks for your reply.....

**For Zoom In/Out...... I have 2 buttons that is +(plus) and -(minus). +(plus) is for image zooming out and -(minus) is for image zooming in.**

Above mentioned link is not applicable for my procedure...... How can i add two buttons with functionality of +(plus) is for zooming out and -(minus) is for zooming in.

Comment: Harika Bhavani Sai Nammi - Change the height and width of the image. Check this out - https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-react-native-images-or-saying-goodbye-to-trial-and-error-b2baaf0a1a4d

Comment: @ Lavaraju - I think you will need to use Redux to keep track of all the steps to implement undo and redo. Redux is very simple and it will help to maintain consistent data and to reduce server requests. I am not sure how to do it without using Redux.